# I have to make a loop taking a users input until "done" is entered

Tags: java, string, loops, arraylist

I'm trying to make an `ArrayList` that takes in multiple names that the user enters, until the word `done` is inserted but I'm not really sure how.  How to achieve that?

Comment: Any particular programming language you are using ? Anyway, at least post some code of your attempt, or this question will get closed tue to lack of effort.

Comment: its java sorry forgot to add

Comment: Are you expected to insert "done" as part of the list?  What code have you done to motivate a solution to this problem?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
String userInput;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    userInput = scanner.next();
    if (userInput.equals("done")) {
        break;
    } else {
        names.add(userInput);
    }
}       
scanner.close();
```

Comment: Because using a break rather than the loop conditional is harder to read. while (!userInput.equals("done")) makes more sense when reading the code

Comment: And slightly worse readability of code is now enough reason for a downvote around here?

Comment: I didn't do the downvote game, just suggesting why this answer may not be as good as the other

Answer (score 1):

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String input = null;
    while (!"done".equals(input)) {
        //  prompt the user to enter an input
        System.out.print("Enter input: ");

        //  open up standard input
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


        //  read the input from the command-line; need to use try/catch with the
        //  readLine() method
        try {
            input = br.readLine();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("IO error trying to read input!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        if (!"done".equals(input) && !"".equals(input))
            list.add(input);
    }
    System.out.println("list = " + list);
```

Comment: Although correct, input.equals("done") or using a variable to hold the break String would usually be preferred. Can I also suggest converting both to upper case, to avoid case sensitivity issues? (Edit: In fact, I've just made the change...)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do it like this -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("Please enter names seperated by newline, or done to stop");
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);     // Use a Scanner.
  List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();    // The list of names (String(s)).
  String word;                                  // The current line.
  while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {               // make sure there is a line.
    word = scanner.nextLine();                  // get the line.
    if (word != null) {                         // make sure it isn't null.
      word = word.trim();                       // trim it.
      if (word.equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {      // check for done.
        break;                                  // End on "done".
      }
      al.add(word);                             // Add the line to the list.
    } else {
      break;                                    // End on null.
    }
  }
  System.out.println("The list contains - ");   // Print the list.
  for (String str : al) {                       // line
    System.out.println(str);                    // by line.
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String[] inputArray = new String[0];
do{
  String input=getinput();//replace with custom input code
  newInputArray=new String[inputArray.length+1];
  for(int i=0; i<inputArray.length; i++){
    newInputArray[i]=inputArray[i];
  }
  newInputArray[inputArray.length]=input
  intputArray=newInputArray;
}while(!input.equals("done"));
```

untested code, take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: sure, down-vote the people who are trying to help you.

Comment: oops, sorry for the blame, I'm new as well :)