# Java Weekday input Validation

Tags: java, string, dayofweek

is there a "tidier" way of writing this code? I'm a stickler for simplicity and this seems a bit too repetitive for me. (I'm changing the days to numbers so that I can use them in their own if statements, if anyone was wondering) Any suggestions?

```
Scanner scanText = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter Day: ");
String weekday = scanText.nextLine();

int day = 0;

if (weekday.equalsIgnorCase("Monday"))
  day = 1;
else if (weekday.equalsIgnorCase("Tuesday"))
  day = 2;
else if (weekday.equalsIgnorCase("Wednesday"))
  day = 3;
else if (weekday.equalsIgnorCase("Thursday"))
  day = 4;
else if (weekday.equalsIgnorCase("Friday"))
  day = 5;
else if (weekday.equalsIgnorCase("Saturday"))
  day = 6;
else if (weekday.equalsIgnorCase("Sunday"))
  day = 7;
else {
  System.out.print("Error! Invalid day: ");
  weekday = scanText.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using JDK 1.8, this code may help you:

```
     List<String> strDays = Arrays.asList("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thusday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" );

     String weekday = scanText.nextLine();

     int day = 0;
     if(strDays.contains(weekday)) {

         day = strDays.indexOf(weekday) + 1;
     } else {
         System.out.print("Error! Invalid day: ");
         weekday = scanText.nextLine();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;


public class DayofWeekExample {

    public static int getIntDayOfWeek(String dayOfWeek)
    {
        try
        {
            DateFormat formatter ;
            Date date ;
            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
            date = (Date)formatter.parse(dayOfWeek);
            GregorianCalendar g = new GregorianCalendar();
            g.setTime(date);
            return g.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        }
        catch (ParseException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception :"+e);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Beginnig day is Sunday

        Scanner scanText = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter Day: ");
        String weekday = scanText.nextLine();

        System.out.println("-> " + getIntDayOfWeek(weekday));


    }
}
```

The first day of the week is derived from the current locale. If you don't set the locale of the calendar ([Calendar.getInstance(Locale)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance(java.util.Locale)), or [new GregorianCalendar(Locale)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar(java.util.Locale))), it will use the system's default.

Comment: This is great, but how can I use this to get user input and then get a number from a specific day?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are basically mapping a `String` value to an `int` value, I think, its a typical use case of `Map`. You can write like below ( one disadvantage being you have to initialize the `Map` but that can be encapsulated for better readability)

```
Scanner scanText = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter Day: ");
        String weekday = scanText.nextLine();

        int day = 0;
        Map<String,Integer> day_of_week=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        day_of_week.put("MONDAY", 1);
        day_of_week.put("TUESDAY", 2);
        day_of_week.put("WEDNESDAY", 3);
        day_of_week.put("THURSDAY", 4);
        day_of_week.put("FRIDAY", 5);
        day_of_week.put("SATURDAY", 6);
        day_of_week.put("SUNDAY", 7);

        if(day_of_week.containsKey(weekday.toUpperCase())){
            day = day_of_week.get(weekday.toUpperCase()).intValue();
        }else{
            System.out.print("Error! Invalid day: ");
              weekday = scanText.nextLine();
        }
```

I am sure you must have thought of going to comparison part again after reading value from `else` block.

Comment: I was wondering about that, how do I make it go back to the beginning of the if statement after the else?

Comment: you will have to put whole thing in a `while` or `do-while` loop and break at any special `String` of your choice . [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20589178/i-have-to-make-a-loop-taking-a-users-input-until-done-is-entered) for Elliott's answer. Instead of `weekday = scanText.nextLine();` , you can simply say `continue` in `else`.